# SHA-3: Implementation of Theta function according to FIPS-202 not behaving as expected

Tags: hash, verilog, sha-3

I'm implementing SHA-3 following the official [FIPS-202 document](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) in Verilog.
My state is represented by a one-dimensional register and I use a macro function to calculate the corresponding state index from the (x,y,z) coordinates in the document:

`A[x, y, z] = S [W(5y + x) + z]`, `W = 64` (p. 9)

I'm strictly following the guide on page 11 and came up with this:

```
// Macros for transforming dimensions
`define sub_1(x) (x == 0 ? 4 : x - 1)
`define add_1(x) (x == 4 ? 0 : x + 1)
`define sub_1_W(x) (x == 0 ? (W - 1) : x - 1)
`define s(x,y,z) ((W * ((5 * y) + x)) + z)
`define s_xz(x,z) ((W * x) + z)

// Wires
wire [0:(1600 - 1)] absorbed_data, after_theta;
wire [0:((5 * 64) - 1)] C, D; 

genvar x, z;
for(x = 0; x < 5; x = x + 1) begin
    for(z = (W - 1); z >= 0; z = z - 1) begin
        // Step 1
        assign C[`s_xz(x,z)] = absorbed_data[`s(x,0,z)] ^ absorbed_data[`s(x,1,z)] ^ absorbed_data[`s(x,2,z)] ^ absorbed_data[`s(x,3,z)] ^ absorbed_data[`s(x,4,z)];
        // Step 2
        assign D[`s_xz(x,z)] = C[`s_xz(`sub_1(x),z)] ^ C[`s_xz(`add_1(x),`sub_1_W(z)];
    end
end    

genvar x, y, z;
generate
    for(x = 0; x < 5; x = x + 1) begin
        for(y = 0; y < 5; y = y + 1) begin
            for(z = 0; z < W; z = z + 1) begin
                // Step 3
                assign after_theta[`s(x,y,z)] = absorbed_data[`s(x,y,z)] ^ D[`s_xz(x,z)];
            end
        end
    end
endgenerate
```

The issue I'm currently facing seems to be in the Theta function. For example for SHA-224 and an empty message should yield the intermediate results and the final output as shown in [this document.](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/SHA3-224_Msg0.pdf)
Strangely, I get the same `absorbed_data` (`06 00 ... 00 80`) but different values for `C` and `D`:

**C**

```
as is: 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
to be: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

**D**

```
as is: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 06 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 | 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
to be: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c
```

Firstly, for `C` the bit order seems to be different but not on the bit-level but on the byte-level (as `06` stays `06`).
Secondly, for `D` I get `06 00 .. 01 00` whereas the correct result should be `00 .. 00 07`. This is never possible for my implementation as, according to FIPS-202, the bit at `z` can only be shifted by one position ( `(z - 1) mod w`).

In the *to-be* case `D` will yield the correct result because `06 ^ (80 << 1) = 07`.

In conclusion, I would say that my implementation behaves as one can expect from the definition in FIPS-202, correct?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution.
It is described in appendix of [FIPS 202](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) B.1 (starting on page 26). A hint on this topic is given on page 25:

> The convention for interpreting hexadecimal strings as bit strings for the inputs and outputs of the SHA-3 examples **is different from the convention for other functions** on the examples page. The conversion functions between hexadecimal strings and SHA-3 bit strings are specified in Sec. B.1. For byte-aligned messages, the hexadecimal forms of the padding for the SHA-3 functions are described in Sec. B.2.

There is a good explanation on how to circumvent this issue on [cryptologie.net](https://cryptologie.net/article/387/byte-ordering-and-bit-numbering-in-keccak-and-sha-3/).